# MPEG Audio Constant bit rate conversion

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, signal-processing, sox, librosa

I am trying to convert few .wav files to .mp3 format

The desired .mp3 format is :

[image]

I tried with FFmpeg with this code :

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -vn -ac 2 -b:a 160k output1.mp3
```

This is the output of this command on one .wav format

[image]

I am getting the result but two things are different
Overall bit rate mode and Writing library

- Writing library: LAME3.99.5 vs LAME3.100 ( I think this shouldn't
  make any problem?)
- bit rate mode Constant Vs variable

How to change bit rate mode from variable to Constant? and do I need to convert using the same Writing library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The output using `ffmpeg -i input.wav -vn -ac 2 -b:a 160k output1.mp3` is constant bit rate, however ffmpeg writes a header with the title Xing and Mediainfo infers that to indicate VBR. Disable writing that header if you want Mediainfo to detect Constant bit rate.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -vn -ac 2 -b:a 160k -write_xing 0 output1.mp3
```

Note that the actual MP3 encoding won't change.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using sox instead of FFmpeg :

```
sox -t wav -r 48000 -b 16 -c 2 file.wav -C 160 -t mp3 sock33.mp3
```

- Sample rate of 48 kHz (-r 48000)
- two channel (-c 2)
- 16 bits bit depth (-b 16)